# Dijkstra’s algoritm

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image]

Is it correct that the shortest path from a to z is 12, and that the path is abehz? I used Dijkstra’s algorithm.

Comment: $abehiz$ is shorter.

Comment: I suggest a two source accounting, find the shortest distances from `a' to each of `e,f,g'   and a separate version from `z' to `e,f,g' Fewer surprises

Answer (score 0):

There is the shortest path P from a to z(where a,z are vertices in a given graph) of weight 11. The vertex sequence of P is a,b,e,h,i,z.